# Permissions Issue for A Symlinked Directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

I have a web application running on Ubuntu 14.04. The app's deployment service creates separate users, groups and permissions automatically when deploying the app to my server on AWS.

The app runs as a user called `nginx` which is part of a group also called `nginx`. When I ssh in I must do so as another user: `michaelmichael`. I am not part of the `nginx` group.

The app has a `/tmp/cache` dir that I must be able to write to as the `michaelmichael` user in order to manually initialize some settings. When I attempt to do so, I get a 'permission denied' error.

My next step is to check the permissions for the folder. Things start to get confusing. The directory is symlinked so that it can refer to multiple iterations of the application. So, for example, the actual directory that I try to write to is `/var/deploy/my-app/web_head/releases/20150221204050/tmp/cache` If I `ls -l` on this directory I get the following:

> `lrwxrwxrwx 1 nginx nginx 43 Feb 21 20:40
>   /var/deploy/my-app/web_head/releases/20150221204050/tmp/cache ->
>   /var/deploy/my-app/web_head/shared/cache`

If I `ls -l /var/deploy/my-app/web_head/shared` I can see that `cache` is a directory with the following permissions:

> `drwxrwxr-x 14 nginx  nginx        4096 Feb 21 20:31 cache`

So, in order to write to this directory, do I need to add my user, `michaelmichael` to the nginx group? Do I need to modify the permissions of the symlinked directory (the `/releases/` dir), or the directory itself (the `cache` dir)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious answer is sometimes the correct one. 
You need to write to the `cache` directory,
so you need write permission to the `cache` directory. 
The fact that you're able to do the `ls -l` demonstrates
that you have all the necessary access to the `releases` directory.

You can get the desired access by either adding your user to the `nginx` group
or changing the mode of the `cache` directory (probably to 777).

Comment: Yep. Don't know why it wasn't more obvious to me. Easy points!